# Opening multiple tabs with gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

I'm trying to create a command that will open 3 services from the Rails stack, rails s, spork, and autotest. I can run these commands individually by opening 3 terminals, going to the app folder and running them. I can even open 3 new tabs and run the commands on each.

The problem is that they fail when I try to open the tabs via gnome-terminal like so:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --title="rails s" -e "rails s" --tab --title="spork" -e "spork" --tab --title="autotest" -e "autotest"
```

Error (for spork and autotest):

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "spork" (No such file or directory)
```

Surprisingly it does work for 'rails s' (the tab shows the server running).

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that `-e` has been deprecated in newer versions of gnome-terminal, which makes it more tricky to answer the question. To prepare for the deprecation, the best I could come up with is [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637537/63722).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below is an answer from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902909/1626345)

1. Add a `eval "$BASH_POST_RC"` to the end of your .bashrc
2. Set the `BASH_POST_RC` environment variable for each tab to that command you like to execute, e.g.:  `gnome-terminal --working-directory="/home/zardoz/projects/my_rails_app" --tab -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"rails server\"; exec bash"' --tab -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"autotest\"; exec bash"'`

Answer (score 17):

Invoking `gnome-terminal` three times and stringing the commands together with `&&` **won't** work, and the tabs won't appear in the same terminal, and indeed you will have to quit the first terminal for the next to appear.

The way to make sure all your tabs open in one instance of `gnome-terminal` all at the same time is to use the `--tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME` switch. In the command below you can leave the first command as `gnome-terminal --tab` as that it is the first window to be generated; now all you need to know is which profile you are using and you can use `--tab-with-profile=YourProfile` to invoke the other commands and they will all appear at once in the original terminal opened.

Here is your command modified:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --title="rails s" -e "rails s" --tab-with-profile=Default --title="spork" -e "spork" --tab-with-profile=Default --title="autotest" -e "autotest"
```

(For future readers: substitute the program names given after `-e` to test out the command line given here; remember your targets for `-e` must be installed and in `$PATH`; for things not in `$PATH` use an absolute path such as, for example, `/opt/mike/program`)

Remember to specify the actual profile you are using for the `--tab-with-profile` switches. The first invocation of `gnome-terminal` must use `--tab` and all the rest `--tab-with-profile`. With this method it should be possible to open a large number of tabs all in the same instance of `gnome-terminal`.

Find the profile you are currently using by right clicking in `gnome-terminal` and look at profiles and there will be a marker on the one you are currently using:

[image]

Go to Profile preferences for more information and to check the name of the profile.

For more information, see `man gnome-terminal` and the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html).

---

**Note**:

If you have trouble launching your programs with `gnome-terminal`, either add the location to `$PATH`, or make a symlink and place it in a `$PATH` location, or (what was very useful here): create a simple bash wrapper script and call that in the `gnome-terminal` command line above. (You must call it with an absolute path: i.e. `/location/of/script` and not just the name of it.)

As an example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cd $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin 
spork
exit 0
```

Then name the script, make it executable and call it in the `gnome-terminal` command line above. Do this for all the non repo programs that are problematic.

Comment: How do I know the profile? (I tried with Default, my username, and ~/.profile)

Comment: It says Default but I get the same error using --tab-with-profile=Default

Comment: @Manuel The other possibility is the target commands aren't in your `$PATH`;specify the location of `spork` and the others with an absolute path.

Comment: The command I'm using is gnome-terminal --tab --title="rails s" -e "rails s" --tab-with-profile=Default --title="spork" -e "spork" --tab-with-profile=Default --title="autotest" -e "autotest" (copy/paste from your answer). About $PATH, if this is the problem then why does it work on a tab opened via the menu?

Comment: @Manuel As you say in your question, you have to go to "the app folder" and run them from there, which means they are not in `$PATH`. The method in the answer is the one I use to launch all repository installed command-line programs in different tabs in the same `gnome-terminal` window, and it always works, as those other programs are in $PATH.

Comment: I added the spork dir to the path but I still can't run it on a separate terminal using gnome-terminal (tab or otherwise). This is so frustrating because I can run it, just not with "gnome-terminal -e spork". Edit: I also added the app folder to no avail.

Comment: I also tried with the option --working-directory set to the app folder, still not getting any.

Comment: @Manuel Can you give me the link to the download, if the programs weren't installed from the repos? Then I can test with these particular programs.

Comment: I installed ruby 2.0 (rvm install 2.0.0) and spork (gem install spork). spork's path is $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin

Comment: @Manuel See my edit: a bash wrapper script might do it if you did one for all of the programs.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-terminal --tab -- sh -c "python3 'test.py' ;  bash"`

this code open new tab in terminal running a python script and when its over, this new tab will not close, because i added 'bash' in the end of this code...

if you want it multiple times, put it into a while loop in your bash script

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in other Q&A, the only straightforward, non-deprecated way to open multiple tabs is to issue the command multiple times, such as the answer at Unix & LInux to the question, [Opening new gnome-terminal (v3.28+) with multiple tabs and different commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/526559/17300), by [Владимир Савостин](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/359258/%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80-%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD).

```
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "myCommand -some-args; bash"
gnome-terminal -- bash -c "myOtherCommand -some-args; bash"
```

If I want to extract a longer expression from each command, it seems I had to create a script and call that, which I did in place of using `; bash` to keep the window open.  I used a simple run_cmd.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

display_success() {
  read -p "Exited with success; press enter to exit..."
}

display_error() {
  read -p "Exited with error value $1; press enter to exit..."
}

run_cmd() {
  echo "Running: $@"
  "$@" && display_success || display_error $?
}

run_cmd "$@"
```

I then replaced `bash -c` with `run_cmd.sh`.  Since that script is trivial, please consider it as in the public domain.