# How to open several Terminal Tabs and open files in Vim and change directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, vim

I'm asking this question because I tried a lot of solutions I found and they all didn't work:

- `gnome-terminal --save-config=...` results in an error that this option is no more possible
- `gnome-terminal --tab -- 'vim ~/Files/file.txt'` for creating a shell script results in an error, my system is in German but it seems to be like

  ```
  There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
  Failed to execute child process "vim ~/Files/file.txt" (No such file or directory)
  ```

  and does nothing but using just `vim` without a file to open works
- using a [session manager](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/04/gnome-save-and-restore-running.html) just opens the Terminal automatically but without any tabs
- and `gnome-terminal --tab -- 'cd ~/Files/'` doesn't work either (error like the one above)

The version is `# GNOME Terminal 3.28.2 using VTE 0.52.2 +GNUTLS -PCRE2`.
Maybe there are mistakes in my ways of solving it or you know another (a better) alternative?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Does [Opening multiple tabs with gnome-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/277543/507051) help?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I hope I understand it right but setting the variable in `.bashrc` and typing `gnome-terminal --tab -- 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"vim todo.txt\"; exec bash"'` doesn't work, too.

Comment: No, I think you should add the line `eval "$BASH_POST_RC"` (literally!) to the end of your `~/.bashrc` and run e.g.: `gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c "export BASH_POST_RC=\"vim todo.txt\"; exec bash"' --working-directory="$HOME/Files" --tab -e 'exec bash'` I’m not sure about the last ` -e 'exec bash'`, try with and without it.

Comment: With the last phrase it opens 2 tabs, one with the working-directory and one with the error I had before. And without the last phrase only one tab with the directory.

Comment: Will something like this do? [Spawn new Terminator tabs from Bash script](//askubuntu.com/a/869846) Also see [How to open terminal, split to 9 terminals and switch between them using one script?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/168445)

Comment: Thank you. I'll read about Terminator. Good hint. An other version of `gnome-terminal` isn't a possibility for solving my wish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can find that would do this involves creating multiple scripts. `gnome-terminal` has changed over the years and the `-x` and `--command` options have been heavily deprecated. Your best bet is to create profiles for each of the tabs you want to run and use:

```
gnome-terminal --tab-with-profile=Something1 --tab-with-profile=Something2
```

If you're using stuff like `~` or `*` inside your commands it's likely those *won't* be evaluated since that's actually the job of the shell (bash) whereas `gnome-terminal`, so it might help to create an actual script somewhere and tell `gnome-terminal` to use that.

Comment: Using `/home/username/` instead of `~/` and it works. Thank you. Maybe there is a more flexible solution because of having to use lots of profiles for different Terminal layouts.

Answer (score 0):

The script open new tabs:

1. saves in `pathtabs.list` a list of (foo-test) paths to new terminal tabs;
2. creates a new script `autotab.sh` to `xdotool`-FORMAT any list of paths adding <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> shortcuts and `cd`s to commands;
3. `autotab.sh` is useful to xdotool format `<any-list-of-paths>`;
4. usage: `autotab.sh <any-list-of-paths>`;
5. creates `foo_*` test dirs for the `pathtabs.list`;
6. runs `./autotab.sh pathtabs.list` and saves output to new script `maketabs.sh`
7. `maketabs.sh` is useful to open the same set of tabs/paths from the original `pathtabs.list`;

...and runs commands:

8. saves in `pathncommtabs.list` a list of (foo-test) paths and commands to run in new terminal tabs;
9. creates a new script `autopctab.sh` to `xdotool`-FORMAT any list of paths and commands adding <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> shortcuts, `;` and `cd`s to commands;
10. `autopctab.sh` is useful to `xdotool` format `<list-of-paths-and-commands>` (see `pathncommtabs.list`);
11. usage: `autopctab.sh <list-of-paths-and-commands>`; (see `pathncommtabs.list`)
12. runs `./autopctab.sh pathncommtabs.list` and saves the command list to new script `makepctabs.sh`
13. `makepctabs.sh` is useful to open the same set of tabs/paths/commands from the original `pathncommtabs.list`;

```
#open-several-tabs-with-xdotool-slowly-and-easily
#!/bin/bash
#pathtabs.list
if [ ! -f ~/pathtabs.list ]; then
echo ~/foo_00 > pathtabs.list
echo ~/foo_00/foo_00_1 >> pathtabs.list
echo ~/foo_00/foo_00_2 >> pathtabs.list
echo ~/foo_00/foo_00_2/foo_00_2_1 >> pathtabs.list
fi
echo 'pathtabs.list: has a list of paths for the new tabs'

#mkdirs
if [ ! -d ~/foo_00/ ]; then
mkdir foo_00
mkdir foo_00/foo_00_1
mkdir foo_00/foo_00_2
mkdir foo_00/foo_00_2/foo_00_2_1
fi
echo 'mkdirs: testing foo_*' 

##commtabs.list
if [ ! -f ~/commtabs.list ]; then
echo nano newfile1.txt > commtabs.list
echo nano newfile2.txt >> commtabs.list
echo nano newfile3.txt >> commtabs.list
echo nano newfile4.txt >> commtabs.list
fi
echo 'commtabs.list: has a list of commands to run on the new tabs'

#pathtabs.list+commtabs.list+options
if [ ! -f ~/pathncommtabs.list ]; then
cat pathtabs.list |sed 's/.*/cd &;/'|sed '1s/^/c+s+t;/'|\
paste - commtabs.list|tr -d '\t' |sed '$!s/$/;c+s+t/' > pathncommtabs.list
fi
echo 'pathncommtabs.list: integrates pathtabs.list+commtabs.list+cd+;+(new-tab-tokens)'

#autopctab.sh <anypathncommtabs.list>
if [ ! -f ~/autopctab.sh ]; then
echo '#!/bin/bash' > autopctab.sh
echo 'cat $1| sed '\''s/ /#/g'\''| sed '\''s/\(.\)/\1 /g'\''|sed '\''s/#/space/g'\''|\
    sed '\''s/~/asciitilde/g'\''|sed '\''s/_/underscore/g'\''|sed '\''s/c + s + t/control+shift+t/g'\''|\
    sed '\''s/\//slash/g'\''|sed '\''s/\./period/g'\''|sed '\''s/;/Return/g'\''|\
    sed '\''s/.*/xdotool key --delay 18  & Return/'\''' >> autopctab.sh
chmod u+x autopctab.sh
fi
echo 'autopctab.sh: xdotool-format paths+commands+(xdotool-commands)'

#run autopctab.sh <pathncommtabs.list>
#makepctabs.sh
if [ ! -f ~/makepctabs.sh ]; then
echo '#!/bin/bash' > makepctabs.sh
./autopctab.sh pathncommtabs.list >> makepctabs.sh
chmod u+x makepctabs.sh
fi
echo 'makepctabs.sh: run xdotool command lines to OPEN new tabs AND RUN commands with pathncommtabs.list'

#autotab.sh <anytabs.list>
if [ ! -f ~/autotab.sh ]; then
echo '#!/bin/bash' > autotab.sh
echo 'cat $1|sed '\''s/.*/cd &/'\''|sed '\''s/ /#/g'\''|\
    sed '\''s/\(.\)/\1 /g'\''|sed '\''s/#/space/g'\''|\
    sed '\''s/~/asciitilde/g'\''|sed '\''s/_/underscore/g'\''|\
    sed '\''s/\//slash/g'\''|sed '\''s/\./period/g'\''|\
    sed '\''s/.*/xdotool key --delay 18 control+shift+t space c d space asciitilde Return & Return c l e a r Return/'\'''  >> autotab.sh
chmod u+x autotab.sh
fi
echo 'autotab.sh: xdotool-format ONLY paths+(xdotool-commands)'

#run autotab.sh <pathtabs.list>
#maketabs.sh
if [ ! -f ~/maketabs.sh ]; then
echo '#!/bin/bash' > maketabs.sh
./autotab.sh pathtabs.list >> maketabs.sh
chmod u+x maketabs.sh
fi
echo 'maketabs.sh: run xdotool command lines ONLY to open new tabs with pathtabs.list'

#run-maketabs?
#./maketabs.sh

#remove-maketabs.sh?

#remove-autotab.sh?
#rm autotab.sh

#remove-pathtabs.list?
#rm pathtabs.list

#run-makepctabs?
#./makepctabs.sh

#remove-makepctabs.sh?
#rm makepctabs.sh

#remove-autopctab.sh?
#rm autopctab.sh

#remove-pathncommtabs.list?
#rm pathncommtabs.list

#remove-dirs?
#rm -r foo_0?

#echo See also 'https://askubuntu.com/a/380320'
#echo '        https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/'
#echo '        https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool'
```